# Heroku requirements

Tags: python, heroku

I'd tried to deploy my app on Heroku, but smth went wrong.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement get==2019.4.13 (from -r /tmp/build_53ad6d03_/requirements.txt (line 17)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for get==2019.4.13 (from -r /tmp/build_53ad6d03_/requirements.txt (line 17))```

All requirements was loaded, exept get,post and request. What am i doing wrong?

"get" isnt standalone part but a found this in venv
[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CAF0.png)

my requirements file is:

```
astroid==2.4.2
autopep8==1.5
bandit==1.6.2
blinker==1.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.3
dominate==2.4.0
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
flake8==3.7.9
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
get==2019.4.13
gitdb2==3.0.2
GitPython==3.0.8
gunicorn==20.0.4
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
Jinja2==2.10.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mypy==0.780
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
numpy==1.17.4
openpyxl==3.0.3
pandas==0.25.3
pbr==5.4.4
post==2019.4.13
public==2019.4.13
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pyflakes==2.1.1
pylint==2.5.3
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3
query-string==2019.4.13
request==2019.4.13
six==1.13.0
smmap2==2.0.5
SQLAlchemy==1.3.13
stevedore==1.32.0
toml==0.10.1
typed-ast==1.4.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==0.16.0
wrapt==1.12.1
WTForms==2.2.1
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter==1.2.8
```

It was created by using `pip freeze requirements`. If i delete get,post,requets requirements project delpoy but appears another one error with get and post methods

Comment: [`get` isn't a package on PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=get). What are you actually trying to do? "All requirements was loaded, exept get,post and request"—`get` and `post` are HTTP verbs; I'd be surprised if they existed as standalone libraries.

Comment: It's a good idea to use the same `requirements.txt` in development and production. You'd have caught this with a simple `pip install -r requirements.txt` in your local virtualenv.

Comment: @Chris they exist as libraries, but were removed - see comments in https://stackoverflow.com/q/62927162/9171260 for relevant discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same thing suddenly happens to me today. Commenting out in the requirement file the lines for

> get==

and

> post==

eliminates the error and the app still works as usual, but I have not understood what happened under the hood yet