# No matching distribution found for multiple packages

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pypi

Suddenly I get a lot of errors while trying to use my previously working (for many months) requirements file.
I tried to go to the pypi.org and get the same 404 error.

Is there something wrong with my setup?

```
> pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting get==2019.4.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Exception:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/get/
```

If I remove line `get==2019.4.13` next error is:

```
> pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting post==2019.4.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Exception:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/post/
```

Comment: can you check if can connect to pypi or not by using curl? maybe this can be because you are behind a proxy and need to config proxy for pip to work

Comment: I tried from browser (from different location) and got the same 404.

Comment: The package seems to be removed from PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/get/. There is an old version at https://test.pypi.org/project/get/ The maintainer is "russianidiot", I remember she(?) removed a lot of her(?) packages from PyPI and Github: https://github.com/russianidiot

Comment: This is awful! Why would anyone delete packages? How I canbe sure my app will work in the future?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62930315/11138259 -- This turned out not to be the actual issue, but some removed package from _russianidiot_ caused confusion in that case as well. -- Don't know what happened with this account, maybe it would be worth raising the concern to [pypi-support](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support), maybe they could shed some light.

Comment: @sinoroc: Some of the content may [have been moved](https://discuss.python.org/t/improving-risks-and-consequences-against-typosquatting-on-pypi/5090) from *russianidiot* to [*andrewp-as-is* on GitHub](https://github.com/andrewp-as-is) and [*andrewp-as-is* on *PyPI*](https://pypi.org/user/andrewp-as-is/).

Answer (score 4):

PyPI administrator here. You probably unintentionally had `request` instead of `requests` in your `requirements.txt` file.

These projects (`request`, `get`, `post`) were removed by their author and no longer exist. You should remove them from your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Thanks. How we can be sure that the "requests" will not be removed some day?

Comment: The `requests` project is a project of the Python Software Foundation itself, not some third-party individual: https://github.com/psf/requests

Comment: But the [*russianidiot* account](https://pypi.org/user/russianidiot/) is still on PyPI (deleted on GitHub).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I have a Django website deployed to [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku). When I pushed my commit it threw errors like this:

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement post==2019.4.13 (from -r /tmp/build_f0948004/requirements.txt (line 26)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for post==2019.4.13 (from -r/tmp/build_f0948004/requirements.txt (line 26))
```

I deleted dependencies below that spat errors in `requirements.txt`:

```
get==2019.4.13
post==2019.4.13
request==2019.4.13
```

And I saved my commit and pushed it. Now it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, remove these lines fix the problem. Just hope it wont cause any problem in my project

Comment: This solution worked for me. I'm now trying to figure out how these dependencies were there in the first place. Anyone have any insight on this?