# Heroku - No matching distribution found for get

Tags: heroku

I'm having wired error when I push my code.
I have connected my project on Github with Heroku. When I push my code to Github, it automatically updates the code on Heroku.

The problem that I'm having is this error:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement get==2019.4.13 (from -r /tmp/build_501b7310_/requirements.txt (line 12)) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for get==2019.4.13 (from -r /tmp/build_501b7310_/requirements.txt (line 12)) !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. !     Push failed`

The problem is with the `get` package version. This is wired because i used this package version on my previous uploads.
Cant understand why now it gives me this error.
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927162/no-matching-distribution-found-for-multiple-packages